# Add multi value to a parameter in sql but my code not work [i'm newbie]

Tags: sql

### *Add multi value to a parameter in sql but this query result is null table, can you help me !*

### Start code

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[USP_LoadCustomerReportWithMultiCategory]
@companyID int , @arrivalDate datetime , @departureDate datetime , @productCategoryID varchar (100)
AS
BEGIN
Select 
Company.CompanyName, 
Customer.CustomerName, 
Customer.ArrivalDate,
SUM((CustomerInfo.ProductQuantity * Product.ProductPriceSell)) as Total            
From 
CustomerInfo , Customer , Product,Company,ProductCategory             
where
CustomerInfo.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID and 
Product.ProductID = CustomerInfo.ProductID and 
Product.ProductCategoryID = ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID and 
Company.CompanyID = Customer.CompanyID and 
Customer.CompanyID = @companyID and 
Customer.ArrivalDate between @arrivalDate and @departureDate and 
CAST(Product.ProductCategoryID AS VARCHAR)  in (@productCategoryID)     
Group By 
Customer.CustomerName,
Company.CompanyName,
Customer.ArrivalDate,

END
GO
```

### End code

Comment: So... What is your question?

Comment: Hi JohnHC, i'm add multi value to a parameter in sql but this query result is null table, can you help me ! for my code is below.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you are using a JOIN syntax that was replaced 25 years ago in ANSI 92 SQL. Most, if not all DBMS vendors would now recommend using explicit JOINs.. [This article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) is SQL Server specific, but a lot of the principles apply to whichever DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some fields in `Group By`:

- `ProductQuantity`
- `ProductPriceSell`
- `CustomerID`
- `ProductID`
- `ProductCategoryID`
- `CompanyID`

Please add those into the  `Group By` section.

Comment: tks Md. Saifur Rahman, but it still null result when added  ProductQuantity, ProductPriceSell,...

Comment: Hey, may be you should share the result (doesn't matter null). It will clear up confusion on running sp correctly or not.
Is it possible your arrivalDate and departureDate are same?